# How to commit hg repo with GIT submodule which should be read only?

Tags: xcode, git, mercurial, restkit, git-submodules

my Hg repo now needs to include a Git submodule (Restkit) as per the advised method in the site wiki.
However, I am not updating the git contents and should only be potentially reading/pulling in changes from the host.
It appears that when I came to make my first push of my main Hg repo it baulked at the Git one asking for a password. I think this may be because its attempting to authenticate against the Git site as well.
My questions are can I arrange this so that the Git repo is read-only(pull) or even static and/or get round the log in issue. Obviously the two different repos have different credentials.
Thanks.
P.S. using Atlassian SourceTree 1.5.3 on OS X 10.8.2, Xcode 4.5.1

I've just re-read this;

> 2.6. Synchronizing in subrepositories
>
> Subrepos don't automatically track the latest changeset of their sources. Instead, they are updated to the changeset that corresponds with the changeset checked out in the top-level changeset. This is so developers always get a consistent set of compatible code and libraries when they update.
>
> Thus, updating subrepos is a manual process. Simply run 'hg pull' and 'hg up' in the target subrepo, test in the top-level repo, then commit in the top-level repo to record the new combination. The onsub extension can be used to automate that.

Assume this means its not pulling the sub? but I still have the above issue of the password request.

Answer (score 0):

You moved in the right direction, but not finished all required steps.

You have to *have subrepository*, create it by hand... and don't mix **real subrepository** with **a) independent b) nested repository**

When you'll convert nested to subrepo push into master repo will not perform push to subrepo (except it requested)